# Detect BadRequest with a test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mstest

I have two projects: Api and Api.Tests

I want to send invalid DTOs to the API, and then check that I receive BadRequest (status code).

My code:

```
var user = new UserDTO {...};
IActionResult response = await new UsersController().Post(user);

Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response, typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestResult));
```

Error:

> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) Result2 Message:    Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected
>   type:. Actual
>   type:

The error says I have received "Ok", but I have checked it with Postman, and I receive BadRequest.

Comment: Isolated unit tests would produce a different result when compared to integration tests with Postman. consider local integration test with an in-memory TestServer. Reference [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: How are you validating the model? Is it through `DataAnnotation`?

Comment: @AnkitVijay With fluent validation https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration

Comment: The fluent validation would return the bad request before it reaches controller. That is why you would get bad request from Postman. You would need to create integration test instead of unitntest to validate your scenario